# SSL in websockets in glassfish 4.0 Java EE7

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, websocket

I'm developing a websockets application in glassfish 4.0. Everything is working fine when not using SSL but i can't put things to work when SSL is in use.

---

I'm using an annotated Java object as a server:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/{sessionID}")
public class WebSocketServerEndPoint {...}
```

---

On the client side i use the following javascript:

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket('wss://domain.com:8181/websocketserver/websocket/sessionXXX');
```

---

In the deployment descriptor web.xml i have something to make sure the application can't be accessed by other means than ssl:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Protected resource</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <!-- deny all methods other than GET in all url -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>protected</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method-omission>GET</http-method-omission>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>
```

---

I have tested https by visiting index.html test page, which shows correctly.

```
https://domain.com:8181/websocketserver/index.html
```

Any thoughts about why ssl is not working when using websockets but works fine when using https?

Comment: By any chance slash at the end of the URL helps? Like this: 
var webSocket = new WebSocket('wss://domain.com:8181/websocketserver/websocket/sessionXXX/');

Comment: That is not the problem because when i use the websocket without ssl i write: new WebSocket('ws://domain.com:8080/websocketserver/websocket/sessionXXX'); without the slash.

Comment: Have you tried to append slash for SSL? In case of SSL it could be a solution. Even if it works without slash for non-SSL connections, it may not work for SSL

Comment: Hi, just to make sure i tried appending the backslash to the end. The result is the same. Server does not react at all and on the client side the readystate is 3, which means the connection is closed or could not be open.